# How to add additional custom translation for a payment processor?

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, localisation, translation, transifex

I have installed a payment processor extension and it is only in english by default. The vendor delivered a .po and a .mo file with a german translation of the extension. What is the best way to implement the translation of the extension? As I'm new to CiviCRM and following what i have read in the [documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extension+translation) i need to do it via a team on the Transifex project?

Is this the only way? Or can i do it manually as well? It is connected to a drupal CMS and i know how to translate custom modules in drupal.

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just after starting the bounty i have found what i was looking for:

To merge two .po files you'll need to use some shell magic. I did the following:

- extract the original civicrm.mo file to a .po file with this gettext-command: `msgunfmt civicrm.mo -o civicrm.po` to an empty folder
- paste the .po file of the extension to the same folder
- merge the two .po files with this command: `msgcat --use-first *.po | msgfmt -o civicrm.mo -`
- replace the original civicrm.mo file on the server with the newly created one
- clear cache

This is working for me. The extension is translated.